# undo ax.set_yticks([])

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I use an existing script to plot a very specific data type. The script returns an ax object.
These ax objects are used to populate subplots in an new bigger main plot.

In the main script somewhere,

```
ax.set_yticks([])
```

is called. Usually this is wanted. For one of the individual plotting scripts I would like to simply undo this and have matplotlib set my y ticks automatically depending on the data just as if `ax.set_yticks([])` had never been called.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the tick locator before you call set_yticks([]) and restore it later

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(range(10), range(10), 'ko')

#store the yticks locator
l = ax.yaxis.get_major_locator()


#hide ticks and display the figure
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.gcf().show()
raw_input('pause') # => no more yticks

#restore the tick locator to its originale state
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(l)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()  #refresh the plot to sow the yticks again

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would however mean that i have to modifiy the existing script, which i do not want to do for many reasons. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: In this case, you can create a new tick locator instead of storing the original one, the default locator is matplotlib.ticker.Autolocator, but there are some others that you can find here https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html